# Input a value from a combobox, while committing an Add in DataGridView

Tags: c#, database, linq, datagridview, combobox

Using C# and forms. I have a datagridview which has two of the three fields visible in the table which is editable and addable. The third field is in a combobox.
 When updating the database (hitting enter after adding in the empty row) I get an error saying that the third field can't be null. I'd like to have the value in the combobox be used for the third field.

I can't seem to figure it out. Should I be using an event, somehow?

```
private void cmbMCID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cMarks = (from cm in DB.Student_Courses
                      where cm.CID == Convert.ToInt32(cmbMCID.Text)
                      select cm).ToList();

        Student_Course sc = new Student_Course();
        //cMarks.Add(sc);
        studentCourseBindingSource.DataSource = cMarks;
        sc.CID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbMCID.Text);
        //studentCourseBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

    }
```

I've attempted to added a RowsAdded Event but didn't come out on top.

```
private void dgvSMarks_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            Student_Course sc = new Student_Course();
            sc.CID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbMCID.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've made a little progress by using `dgvSMarks.Rows[e.RowIndex-1].Cells[0].Value = 10;` in the RowsAdded event handler. Now just having trouble with foreign keys. heh

Answer (score 0):

Great, OK. so I was doing horrible things - with the combobox. A mix of needing to making a selection in the combobox first (otherwise returned null) and trying to commit what was already in the database.

Needed to create a for loop through the dgv collection, too.

```
private void dgvSMarks_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
    //    if (dgvSMarks.ContainsFocus == true)
    //    {
    //        // Get the RowIndex of the CID Cell, and add the combobox MCID value to it
    //        dgvSMarks.Rows[e.RowIndex-1].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmbMCID.Text);
    //    }
        var student_course = new Student_Course();
        var course = new Course();
        //MessageBox.Show("Row Count is " + dgvSMarks.Rows.Count);
        for (int i = 1; i < dgvSMarks.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == (dgvSMarks.Rows.Count - 1))
            {

                student_course.CID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbMCID.Text);
                student_course.SID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvSMarks.Rows[i - 1].Cells[1].Value);
                student_course.Mark = Convert.ToInt32(dgvSMarks.Rows[i - 1].Cells[2].Value);

                DB.Student_Courses.InsertOnSubmit(student_course);


                DB.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks to the help of my CPI instructors. :)

Comment: I've since realized that a cleaner, simpler and easier way is to use event Validators. So currently messing with cellValidating and rowValidated.